# ExtJS POST on Button Click

Tags: extjs

I have a button that I would like to press and take me to a webpage.  I need to include post data with the request and would like to receive HTML to put inside an iframe.

This is what I think the code would look

```
buttons: [
        {
            text: "link",
            handler: function(){
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'http://www.createbarcode.com/',
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {
                        barcodeData: Ext.getCmp('BarcodeField')
                    },
                    success: function(response, conn) {
                        //Create iframe window with response HTML
                    },
                    failure: function(response, conn) {
                        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                        alert("Failure: " + data.msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Comment: Having href: 'www.google.com', target: '_blank' on a button will take you to a webpage in a new tab. How do I include POST data and open the webpage in the new tab?

Comment: Why would you want to open the webpage in a new tab? If you do that, you're Ext JS app isn't going to be able to know about the results of the response. It sounds like you need to better design and describe what it is that you need to do and then ask about how to accomplish it.

Comment: I do not know how to get this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=as4#fiddle/as4 to put the data from the Barcode Information textfield into the textfield on: http://www.freebarcodes.com/generate_hibcc.asp

Comment: If you need to generate barcodes then, IMO, the better option is to use some javascript barcode library. My google search revealed some, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/pendensproditor/6MLaR/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, not sure if its right, but it works and might point someone in the right direction

```
    //Load scripts 
    Ext.Loader.loadScript('bwip-js/bwip.js');
    Ext.Loader.loadScript('bwip-js/lib/baropts.js');
    Ext.Loader.loadScript('bwip-js/lib/canvas.js');
    Ext.Loader.loadScript('bwip-js/lib/jquery-1.4.1.js');
    Ext.Loader.loadScript('bwip-js/lib/needyoffset.js');
    Ext.Loader.loadScript('bwip-js/lib/symdesc.js');
    Ext.Loader.loadScript('bwip-js/bwipp/code128.js');
```

This was pretty much copied from the bwipjs demo code

```
buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Generate Code',
            handler: function(){
                var elt = Ext.getCmp('symbol').getValue();
                var text = Ext.getCmp('symtext').getValue().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
                var altx = Ext.getCmp('symaltx').getValue().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
                var opts = Ext.getCmp('symopts').getValue().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');

                BWIPJS.load = function(path) {
                }

                var bw = new BWIPJS;

                var tmp = opts.split(' ');
                opts = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                    if (!tmp[i])
                        continue;
                    var eq = tmp[i].indexOf('=');
                    if (eq == -1)
                        opts[tmp[i]] = bw.value(true);
                    else
                        opts[tmp[i].substr(0, eq)] = bw.value(tmp[i].substr(eq+1));
                }

                // Add the alternate text
                if (altx)
                    opts.alttext = bw.value(altx);

                // Add any hard-coded options required to fix problems in the javascript
                // emulation.
                opts.inkspread = bw.value(0);
                if (needyoffset[elt.sym] && !opts.textxalign && !opts.textyalign &&
                    !opts.alttext && opts.textyoffset === undefined)
                    opts.textyoffset = bw.value(-10);

                bw.bitmap(new Bitmap);

                bw.scale(2,2);

                bw.push(text);
                bw.push(opts);

                try {
                    bw.call(elt);
                    bw.bitmap().show('canvas','N');
                } catch(e) {
                    var s = '';
                    if (e.fileName)
                        s += e.fileName + ' ';
                    if (e.lineNumber)
                        s += '[line ' + e.lineNumber + '] ';
                    alert(s + (s ? ': ' : '') + e.message + elt);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```